# inbox: get last message from pms

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'pms' (personal messages). Columns are 'fromid','toid','timesent','msg', 'seen'.

I have an inbox page, where I only want to show the last message from all conversations for the 'current user' = 1. For example

```
[fromid | toid | timesent | msg    |  seen ]
--------------------------------------------
|  1    |  2   |   1:00   | "..."  |   0   |
|  1    |  2   |   1:01   | "..."  |   0   |
|  2    |  1   |   1:02   | "..."  |   1   |
|  3    |  1   |   6:00   | "..."  |   0   |
```

goes to

```
[fromid | toid | timesent | msg    |  seen ]
--------------------------------------------
|  1    |  2   |   1:01   | "..."  |   0   |
|  3    |  1   |   6:00   | "..."  |   0   |
```

returning unique/distinct rows based on columns of fromid and toid with the latest/max timesent. No sent/received messages tab, all on one page.

Ive tried to use `group by` but get `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`
error but when I remove this in mysql my server crashes, and I have to reinstall, and in php it doesn't save or is automatically edited back in.

I've tried to get sent and received messages, instead of all in one inbox:

`select * from pms where fromid = 'someuserid' group by toid`

`select fromid, toid, timesent, msg, seen from pms where fromid = 'someuserid' group by toid`

but cant get past the error above.

I'm also questioning if whether an id column is required since I could use timesent to get the latest message?

Comment: "Ive tried to use group by but get sql_mode=only_full_group_by error but when I remove this in MySQL my server crashes, and I have to reinstall, ...."    Please NEVER remove a setting from MySQL. Especially settings that you do not seem to know the consequences of.   You first need to understand why you did get that error, which is explained here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: im trying to get distinct rows based off of column `toid` using group by, but doesnt work if i only use one column toid, if i use all columns (which i need) then it doesnt return distinct rows, which is what the cmd does?

Comment: What is a conversation?

Comment: The second line in your example does have a `timesent=1:01`.   this seems to be later than the line your are showing in "goes to". Can you explain that?

Comment: a conversation is the data in the table between two users with matching fromid or toid's. fixed timesent typo

Answer (score 1):

You filter using a `WHERE` clause not `GROUP BY`.  One approach uses window functions:

```
select pms.*
from (select pms.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when fromid = 1 then toid else fromid end) order by timesent desc) as seqnum
      from pms 
      where 1 in (fromid, toid)
     ) pms
where seqnum = 1;
```